# Simple script upgraded to take input list. Trouble with upgraded script function

Tags: powershell

I have a somewhat a simple 1 line script that does what I need.  My company in in the middle of a merger integration so there are 2 domains in a forest trust.  I am running this with domain A credentials and pulling most of the data from a corresponding account in domain B.

The 1 liner is belwo and works great.

```
#$cred = Get-Credential
Get-ADUser -filter "userprincipalname -like 'FirstName.LastName@Company.com'" -Properties EmployeeID -credential $cred -server 'us.company.com' | select userprincipalname, EmployeeID, samaccountname
```

Now I need to input a long list of users UPN's and export to a csv.  I have similar scripts that do this but cannot get this one to work. The upgraded script is below.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\fileperm\UsersEmailUPN.txt' |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -filter "userprincipalname -eq $_''" -Properties EmployeeID -credential $cred -server 'us.company.com' } |
    select userprincipalname, EmployeeID, samaccountname
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\fileperm\Output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The output error is -

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'userprincipalname -eq paul.smithy@company.com''' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '23'.
At line:3 char:22
+ ... ch-Object { Get-ADUser -filter "userprincipalname -eq $_''" -Properti ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUse 
   r
```

It is also looking for an 'input object'

cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

Thank you for any input!

Comment: it should be `userprincipalname -eq '$_'` not `userprincipalname -eq $_''`, and you're missing the pipe `|` at the end of line 4 (the `select` line)